# Conversión correcta en fecha SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, cast

Quiero mostrar el mes y el año actual en una consulta SQL, quiero que se vea de la siguiente manera:

**abril/2020**

Intenté esto:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()) + ' / ' + YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Pero, sale el siguiente error:

```
Error de conversión al convertir el valor nvarchar 'Abril / ' al tipo de datos int.
```

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: Year debe estar devolviendo un entero.. tansfromarlo a varchar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es importante cuando necesitas recuperar valores del sistema que dependen de una configuración, establecer el idioma/lenguaje para el que se requieren, pues la misma sentencia para dos logins diferentes puede devolver resultados diferentes.

Creo un usuario con un idioma predeterminado en [us-english]

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [userLogin1] WITH PASSWORD=N'userLogin1', 
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[Lab1], 
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
USE [Lab1]
GO
CREATE USER [userLogin1] FOR LOGIN [userLogin1]
GO
USE [Lab1]
GO
ALTER USER [userLogin1] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
USE [Lab1]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [userLogin1]
GO
```

Creo un usuario con una idioma predeterminado establecido en [Español]

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [userLogin2] WITH PASSWORD=N'userLogin2',
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[Lab1], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[Español], 
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
USE [Lab1]
GO
CREATE USER [userLogin2] FOR LOGIN [userLogin2]
GO
USE [Lab1]
GO
ALTER USER [userLogin2] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
USE [Lab1]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [userLogin2]
GO
```

Ahora ejecutando una de las consultas sin lenguaje establecido, devuelve resultados diferentes para los dos usuarios.

[image: Usuario us-English]

[image: Usuario Español]

La opción pasa por establecer el lenguaje apropiado, independientemente de la conexión.

```
SET LANGUAGE spanish;
DECLARE @DATE DATE;
SET @DATE = GETDATE();
SELECT CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH,@DATE),' / ',DATENAME(YEAR,@DATE));
```

[image: Usuario userLogin1]

[image: Usuario userLogin2]

[Set Language](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Tremenda tu respuesta, muchísimas gracias. Ha sido la más completa :)

Comment: De nada. Un placer poder aportar un granito de conocimiento.

Answer (score 5):

Es porque YEAR regresa entero. Puedes usar la misma función de DATENAME para el año.

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()) + ' / ' + DATENAME(YEAR,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Vaya, pero que bruto he sido. Pensaba que al escribir el DATENAME en YEAR me traería el año escrito en letras. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

`YEAR` devuelve un entero, por lo que podrias usar [`CONCAT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para unir los datos.

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()), ' / ', YEAR(GETDATE()))
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=34fae8e9268f2b31f23670f4fbc7f8a1)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server no puede concatenar de forma implícita una cadena de caracteres con un entero, puedes hacerlo así:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()) + ' / ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(GETDATE()))
```

o bien de la forma que menciona Luis Cazares.

Comment: Es importante siempre asignar la longitud de las cadenas. Luego ocurren muchos bugs por la mala costumbre de no hacerlo.

Comment: Concat convierte implícitamente todos los argumentos en tipos de cadena antes de la concatenación, por tanto la respuesta que mencionas es igual de válida que la otra. No obstante las dos tienen el mismo problema, y es que no tienen en cuenta el idioma.